# Dired-narrow view disappears after using dired-toggle-read-only

Tags: dired, narrowing, read-only-mode

I use the package dired-narrow (which I have bound to `C-x /`) together with `dired-toggle-read-only` (`C-x C-q`). However, if I press `C-c C-c` to commit my changes after using `dired-toggle-read-only` this also makes the `dired-narrow` view disappear. I would like the `dired-narrow` view to persist until I press `g` (which is the default key to undo the `dired-narrow` view.)

Comment: Looking at the source code, this is not easy to do currently because the chosen method of filtering and the provided narrowing string is not stored anywhere or accessible easily with advice. The best solution would be to implement some sort of restore feature in the package itself and then customize dired to call the restore after exit or save of an edit. Hopefully somebody proves me wrong. I don't think this change would be hard to make in the package though.

Comment: I have not found a solution for this as yet but a workaround. Using dired-filter has enabled me to do much the same as dired-narrow but with added features and without the problem described above.